# Does SCPI allow overloaded commands?

Tags: visa

I'm working on implementation of a simple SCPI parser for an instrument that will support VISA API. I wonder if there are any restrictions to support commands that may be called with different set of arguments, like overloaded functions in C++?
Example:

```
SOURCE:POWER <SIGNAL_ID>, <VALUE>
SOURCE:POWER <SIGNAL_GROUP_ID>, <VALUE>
SOURCE:POWER <VALUE>
SOURCE:POWER <CHANNEL_N>, <ON|OFF>
```

Is this allowed? I have read SCPI-99 standard but can't find any direct prohibition to do this.
On the other side if this is allowed then it is not clear what should be returned by `SOUR:POWER?` query.